# cmaps vs plt.style.use. What's the difference?

Tags: matplotlib

I noticed that there are two ways to change the themes of a plot in matplotlib:

1) type the style before the plot: eg:

```
plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")
```

2) using the 'cmap = "seismic"' inside the scatter plot arguments.
eg:

```
scatter1 = ax.scatter(df["age"],df["alpha"], c = df["beta"],cmap = "seismic")
```

I get an error when I try to use cmap = "seaborn-darkgrid" with this error message:

```
ValueError: Colormap seaborn-darkgrid is not recognized. Possible values are: Accent, Accent_r, Blues, Blues_r, BrBG, BrBG_r, BuGn, BuGn_r, BuPu, BuPu_r, CMRmap, CMRmap_r, Dark2, Dark2_r, GnBu, GnBu_r, Greens, Greens_r, Greys, Greys_r, OrRd, OrRd_r, Oranges, Oranges_r, PRGn, PRGn_r, Paired, Paired_r, Pastel1, Pastel1_r, Pastel2, Pastel2_r, PiYG, PiYG_r, PuBu, PuBuGn, PuBuGn_r, PuBu_r, PuOr, PuOr_r, PuRd, PuRd_r, Purples, Purples_r, RdBu, RdBu_r, RdGy, RdGy_r, RdPu, RdPu_r, RdYlBu, RdYlBu_r, RdYlGn, RdYlGn_r, Reds, Reds_r, Set1, Set1_r, Set2, Set2_r, Set3, Set3_r, Spectral, Spectral_r, Wistia, Wistia_r, YlGn, YlGnBu, YlGnBu_r, YlGn_r, YlOrBr, YlOrBr_r, YlOrRd, YlOrRd_r, afmhot, afmhot_r, autumn, autumn_r, binary, binary_r, bone, bone_r, brg, brg_r, bwr, bwr_r, cividis, cividis_r, cool, cool_r, coolwarm, coolwarm_r, copper, copper_r, cubehelix, cubehelix_r, flag, flag_r, gist_earth, gist_earth_r, gist_gray, gist_gray_r, gist_heat, gist_heat_r, gist_ncar, gist_ncar_r, gist_rainbow, gist_rainbow_r, gist_stern, gist_stern_r, gist_yarg, gist_yarg_r, gnuplot, gnuplot2, gnuplot2_r, gnuplot_r, gray, gray_r, hot, hot_r, hsv, hsv_r, inferno, inferno_r, jet, jet_r, magma, magma_r, nipy_spectral, nipy_spectral_r, ocean, ocean_r, pink, pink_r, plasma, plasma_r, prism, prism_r, rainbow, rainbow_r, seismic, seismic_r, spring, spring_r, summer, summer_r, tab10, tab10_r, tab20, tab20_r, tab20b, tab20b_r, tab20c, tab20c_r, terrain, terrain_r, twilight, twilight_r, twilight_shifted, twilight_shifted_r, viridis, viridis_r, winter, winter_r
```

Why can I use 'seaborn-darkgrid' using the 'plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")', but not the cmap method (without stating the obvious!)? Are there two completely separate sets of styles in matplotlib library? One being the cmaps, and the other the plt.styles? Sounds like they are completely distinct in the back end code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styles and cmaps have nothing to do with each other.

Styles are a way to change the appearance of the plot elements. See [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html). Seaborn includes a few pre-defined styles, but you can create your own from scratch.

cmaps are a way to map a value in a given range to a color. See here https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Note that a style can include a default colormap

Comment: Hi, thanks for the links and info. That clears up a lot!